# Python pandas: Finding derivatives from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataframe looks like this:

```
                     date     time   sym        ask0        ask1        ask2  
0     2017-08-21 07:00:00 07:00:00   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
1     2017-08-21 07:00:15 07:00:15   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
2     2017-08-21 07:00:30 07:00:30   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
3     2017-08-21 07:00:45 07:00:45   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
4     2017-08-21 07:01:00 07:01:00   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
5     2017-08-21 07:01:15 07:01:15   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
6     2017-08-21 07:01:30 07:01:30   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
7     2017-08-21 07:01:45 07:01:45   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
8     2017-08-21 07:02:00 07:02:00   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
9     2017-08-21 07:02:15 07:02:15   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
10    2017-08-21 07:02:30 07:02:30   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
11    2017-08-21 07:02:45 07:02:45   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
12    2017-08-21 07:03:00 07:03:00   7YR  100.812500  100.828125  100.843750   
13    2017-08-21 07:03:15 07:03:15   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
14    2017-08-21 07:03:30 07:03:30   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
15    2017-08-21 07:03:45 07:03:45   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
16    2017-08-21 07:04:00 07:04:00   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
17    2017-08-21 07:04:15 07:04:15   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
18    2017-08-21 07:04:30 07:04:30   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
19    2017-08-21 07:04:45 07:04:45   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
20    2017-08-21 07:05:00 07:05:00   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
21    2017-08-21 07:05:15 07:05:15   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375   
22    2017-08-21 07:05:30 07:05:30   7YR  100.828125  100.843750  100.859375
```

I would like to calculate the derivative:
`d = d(ask0)/dt`

where `dt = 2` minutes.

So for example,

```
t = 2017-08-21 07:04:30 07:04:30    ask@t=100.828125 
t-1 =  2017-08-21 07:04:30 07:02:30  ask@t-1=100.812500
dask/dt = (100.828125-100.812500)/2 = 0.0078125
```

I know I can do this by iterating each row in the dataframe.

But I was wondering if there is a Pandas function doing this job.

Comment: `d['ask0'] = d['ask0']/dt`?

Comment: I think you want `d.ask0.diff() / dt`

Comment: That would not work... `d = y2-y1 / dt` I need a way to obtain `y1`

Comment: But I need the difference from 2 minutes ago. `d.ask0.diff() / dt` will calculate the difference in the previous row.

Answer (score 3):

First step is to ensure `date` is a `datetime` column

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

**Solution**

```
df.set_index('date').ask0.rolling('121s').apply(lambda x: x[-1] - x[0]) / 2

date
2017-08-21 07:00:00    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:00:15    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:00:30    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:00:45    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:01:00    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:01:15    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:01:30    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:01:45    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:02:00    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:02:15    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:02:30    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:02:45    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:03:00    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:03:15    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:03:30    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:03:45    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:04:00    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:04:15    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:04:30    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:04:45    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:05:00    0.007812
2017-08-21 07:05:15    0.000000
2017-08-21 07:05:30    0.000000
Name: ask0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that date is a datetime `Series`: `df.date = to_datetime(df.date)`. Make that series the index of your dataframe with `df.set_index('date')`. Then resample the dataframe with a 15-sec step and interpolate:

```
resampled = d.resample('15s').interpolate()
```

Now all rows are at the same time distance and the row 2 minutes ago is the row shifted by 8.

```
resampled['deriv'] = (resampled['ask0'] - resampled['ask0'].shift(8))/2
```

Comment: @EzerK It may. It depends on the original dataset.

Comment: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: But did you set the datetime column as the index?

Comment: Right now I am using a For loop... But execution time is almost 10 minutes for 12,000 rows...

Comment: @DYZ Yes datetime column is the index

Answer (score 1):

If your data is a time series of 15 second intervals you can do

```
d['deriv'] = (d['ask0'] - d['ask0'].shift(8))/2
```

Comment: Close, but that still wouldn't work, because its not always on the same day. If only there was a way to express `.shift()` in terms of `datetime` instead of number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the previous timestamp and merge the df with itself.

something along these lines (here with accommodations for read_clipboard() from your posted sample):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_clipboard()
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

data['combined_date'] =pd.to_datetime(data.level_1+' '+data.date)
data['prev_dt'] = data.combined_date - pd.to_timedelta(2,'m')
new_data = data.merge(data,left_on='prev_dt', right_on='combined_date')[['combined_date_x', 'comm'bined_date_y', 'ask0_x', 'ask0_y']]
new_data['deriv'] = (new_data.ask0_x - new_data.ask0_y)/2
```